# Grub-Customizer made Windows 7 disappear from Grub2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I am running dual-boot Ubuntu 12.04/Windows7. I wanted to change the boot order in Grub2 to have Windows on top of the list.
I installed Grub-Customizer on Ubuntu 12.04 using the following terminal commands copied from another post:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After installing, I launched Grub-Customizer from Dash Home. Windows 7 does not appear in the list. I closed the program and was prompted to save the current settings.
Upon rebooting, Windows did not appear in the Grub2 list.

I went back into Grub-Customizer and clicked the "Revert" button but still no Windows 7.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Try this `sudo update-grub`, and reboot.

Comment: Did you try boot-repair?

Answer (score 1):

Boot-Repair can undo the settings generated by GRUB-Customizer.

Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) --> Advanced Options -> `GRUB options` tab --> tick "`Purge GRUB and reinstall it`" --> Apply

Indicate the URL that will appear if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can run

> sudo update-grub

to generate a new grub config file and let grub detect all the OS installed on your system.

Anyway, if you want to change the deafult entry in GRUB, you can edit the `/etc/default/grub` file. The value of `GRUB_DEFAULT` indicates the default boot item in the grub menu. This settings takes either a string or a numeric value:

### String: menuentry name

You can give to it the entry name in this way:

> GRUB_DEFAULT="Menu entry"

You can take the entry name from this file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. In it you will find some lines starting with "menuentry", the string between the " " indicates the entry name.

### Numeric value: entry number

You can also give an "entry number" instead of the entry name to `GRUB_DEFAULT`. For example, if you want the second entry to be the default, just edit like this:

> GRUB_DEFAULT=2

Here too, you can see the entry number inside the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` counting the "menuentry" lines.

**Don't forget to run a `sudo update-grub` after the modifications in order to make changes to `GRUB_DEFAULT` into the real grub config.**