# Issues with Ubuntu/Win7 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 13.10, windows-7, bootloader

Hi I'm a newbie to Linux and have been interested in trying it out. My wife has no interest in it so I'm forced to create a dual OS situation but I've really run into a brick wall here.

I've done as much Google searching and read as many tutorials as I can but this just isn't working. I have two HDDs that I can use. One has Win7 installed, but as soon as I installed Ubuntu on the other drive Windows refuses to boot. I tried using my 7 disk to repair the bootloader which didn't work, and I also tried to install grub which also did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use Boot Repair and post the repair log.

Comment: Windows 7 boot repair or some Ubuntu boot repair?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Ok cool it did do a thing and at boot I now have the grub menu. Windows 7 is not there though. Here's that url you asked for http://paste.ubuntu.com/7037700/

Comment: OK. Boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub2` in the Terminal.

Comment: Ok I did that and it found linux image, initrd image, and memtest86+

Comment: It should find Windows 7 (loader). Did it? If not, you should set up it manually. Use Grub Customizer to do it simply.

Comment: alright I have installed the customizer and refreshed it a few times but windows still is not there. do I need to run boot-repair again as suggested by this thread? http://askubuntu.com/questions/361896/grub-customizer-made-windows-7-disappear-from-gurb2

Comment: This can be marked as solved. Your advice helped tremendously and I appreciate it. It took a little more work than I thought it would take. It required a new install of Windows. But I did that, shrank the partition down in Windows. Then I booted up the live CD and installed Ubuntu. After that was done I used the boot-repair you mentioned. Now I can switch between the two seamlessly. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to see that you solved your problem, but there was a more straight way to do it than reinstalling Windows. I'll answer down here, if you allow.

Comment: If Danatela's answer was helpful to you, you shold mark it as accepted answer. This is a polite way to say Thanks to person who helped you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to install and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Choose Recommended Repair.

Once you have done it, boot into Ubuntu, then run

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Normally, that's all. You should not care for Windows, as it will find it for you. If not, repair the Windows' MBR and repeat Boot-Repair recommended procedure. There is alternate way if you want to make Windows entry manually.

### Enabling Windows manually

Edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Microsoft Windows 7" {
        insmod ntfs
        set root='(hd0,1)'
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}
```

Run

```
sudo update-grub2
```

And you will see Windows at the end of boot menu.